# How to avoid encode html entities in input using Antisamy

Tags: java, html, html-sanitizing, antisamy

When i'm using antisamy1.5.3 using parser mode as DOM, all the html entities like `&nbsp;` are converted to `&amp;nbsp;`.I don't want this conversion. How to avoid such conversion. In antisamy source code i think this conversion has been done at  ASXHTMLSerializer.getEntityREf() method. Please help how to avoid this encoding.

**Input:**

```
<div class=WordSection1><p class=MsoNormal>Hi,<o:p></o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal>I do have a problem with my product.<o:p></o:p></p></div>
```

**Antisamy output (Cleanresults.getcleanhtml())**

```
<div>
    <p>Hi,</p>&amp;nbsp;<p>I do have a problem with my product.</p></div>
```

**Expected Output:**

```
<div>
        <p>Hi,</p>&nbsp;<p>I do have a problem with my product.</p></div>
```